# MLCP load compressed xml files and skip xml files with a specific xml tag

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, mlcp

I am trying to load xml gzip files and I am breaking the input xml to multiple xml records.. But is there a way in mlcp to ignore a record while loading if a particular xml tag or xml value is present. If not what are my other options ?

Following is my options that I am using now to load the gzip xml file and break to individual records

```
import
-host
xxxxx
-port
xxxx
-username
xxxx
-password
xxxx
-batch_size
1
-input_compressed
true
-input_compression_codec
gzip
-input_file_type
aggregates
-output_collections
wos
-output_permissions
rest-reader,read,rest-writer,update
-output_uri_prefix
/wos/
-output_uri_suffix
.xml
-aggregate_record_element
REC
-aggregate_record_namespace
http://xxxx.yyyy.com
-uri_id
UID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only think of using an MLCP transform (`-transform_module` e.a.) in which you conditionally pass through the $content map:map. Return empty sequence if you want to have a particular aggregate fragment suppressed.

HTH!

Comment: can I use DHF input transform for this will this get invoked before are after the insert of the xml fragment. And also will the trasnform module or transform function is called after the breakup of the records ?

Comment: MLCP splits aggregates first, and calls the transform for each fragment, like it invokes transforms for each delimited record too. Unfortunately, DHF requires its own transform, and not sure if that allows the same trick. Perhaps best to file a ticket against the project itself to ask: https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-data-hub/issues

Comment: Thank you.. looks like DHF input flow is calling after the aggregate split.. AS I was loading with DHF with empty input flow and it worked.. I will try adding the filter in the input flow.